# Filtering text from a Pdf using PyPDF2 to Excel Sheet with nothing Showing

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, xlsxwriter, pypdf

```
import PyPDF2
import re
import xlsxwriter

docsFile = open('image0001.pdf','rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(docsFile)
loanNumberlist = []
loan2Matchlist = []
poolNumlist = []
borrowerNamelist = []
wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('docInfo.xlsx')
ws = wb.add_worksheet('sheet2')
row = 0

columnHeaders = ['Borrower Name', 'Loan Number', 'LD Loan Number', 'Pool #']
for col, colname in enumerate(columnHeaders, start=0):
    ws.write(row, col, colname)
class pdfExtract:
    def __init__(self, pg):
        self.pg = pg
    def extractShit(self):
        pageObj = pdfReader.getpage(self.pg)
        pgData = pageObj.extractText()
        loanNumber = re.split('\\bLoan #:\\b', pgData)[-1]
        loanNumberlist.append(loanNumber)
        loan2Match = re.match(r"?:/\d{0,10}", pgData)[-1]
        loan2Matchlist.append(loan2Match)
        poolNumber = re.split('\\bPool #:\\b',pgData)[-1]
        poolNumlist.append(poolNumber)
        borrowerName =re.split('\\bBorrower #:\\b',pgData)[-1]
        borrowerNamelist.append(borrowerName)
for page in range(0, 223):
    pdfExtract(page)
for row, rowvar in enumerate(borrowerNamelist, start=1):#write Borrower name
   col = 0
   ws.write_string(row, col, rowvar)
for row, lnNM in enumerate(loanNumberlist, start=1):#write loan number 1
   col = 1
   ws.write_number(row, col, lnNM)
for row, lnNM2 in enumerate(loan2Matchlist, start=1):#write loan number 2
    col = 2
    ws.write_number(row, col, lnNM2)
for row, plNm in enumerate(poolNumlist, start=1):#write pool number
    col = 3
    ws.write_number(row, col, plNm)
wb.close()
```

So, I wrote this program to grab data from a pdf file and return 4 things in each page  and put them into an excel file. That looks like: 
Loan #: 0065192080/3000009289 
Pool#: AK1576
Borrower: David h Theman

I have to grab each page get the first loan number, then the second loan number(after the “/“). Then the rest.
It runs through, but all I get to see on the excel file is the headers no data and no errors.
I thought it was how I'm returning the data or how I'm writing it, but it has no changes. Would it have to do with my For loops? The regex code I got from different answers on here.  I've changed how I write it to the excel file, but no luck.

Comment: It looks like you don't call the `extractShit()` method anywhere which probably means that shit hasn't been extracted.